# ASP.Net Custom Client-Side Validation

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have a custom validation function in JavaScript in a user control on a .Net 2.0 web site which checks to see that the fee paid is not in excess of the fee amount due.

I've placed the validator code in the `ascx` file, and I have also tried using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` and in both cases the validation fires, but cannot find the JavaScript function.

The output in Firefox's error console is `"feeAmountCheck is not defined"`. Here is the function (this was taken directly from firefox->view source)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function feeAmountCheck(source, arguments)
    {
        var amountDue = document.getElementById('ctl00_footerContentHolder_Fees1_FeeDue');
        var amountPaid = document.getElementById('ctl00_footerContentHolder_Fees1_FeePaid');

        if (amountDue.value > 0 && amountDue >= amountPaid)
        {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }

        return arguments;
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas as to why the function isn't being found? How can I remedy this without having to add the function to my master page or consuming page?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing the argument names to `sender` and `args`.  And, after you have it working, switch the call over to `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, regardless of AJAX use.

Answer (score 7):

When you're using .Net 2.0 and Ajax - you should use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

It will work better in Ajax environments then the old Page.ClientScript version

Answer (score 0):

While I would still like an answer to why my javascript wasn't being recognized, the solution I found in the meantime (and should have done in the first place) is to use an `Asp:CompareValidator` instead of an `Asp:CustomValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use:

```
var amountDue = document.getElementById('<%=YourControlName.ClientID%>');
```

That will automatically resolve the client id for the element without you having to figure out that it's called `'ctl00_footerContentHolder_Fees1_FeeDue'`.